# Returning the address of a char* variable

Tags: c++, string, char

I'm currently developing a project and in one of my functions, I need to return the address of a `char*` variable.
Or maybe it's better to return the address of my string, but I don't know how to do this.

This is my code:

```
const char* rogner(){

    int tableauXY[2];

    tableauXY[0]=5;
    tableauXY[1]=8;

    string valeurs=to_string(tableauXY[0])+";"+to_string(tableauXY[1]);

    const char* val1=valeurs.c_str();
    return val1;
}
```

Comment: both would be wrong, since both addresses refer to a) a local variable itself (if you return `&valeurs`), or b) to some resource managed by a local variable with RAII semantics (if you return `val1`). Those pointers would both be invalid after the function returned, and using them in any way would result in undefined behavior.

Comment: Well, this code is C++ but in fact, it's a dll whose interact with a webdev projet (IDE) and it only support C thats why i must declare function with this line before: extern "C"__declspec(dllexport)

Comment: @JoffreyAuray-Lorival  Since it is a DLL, the direction that your question should take is different than your original question.  The real question should be "how do I pass and send strings from a DLL to an application?".

Comment: @JoffreyAuray-Lorival `I need to return the address of a char* variable.` Not when you're talking about DLL's -- it isn't so simple as that.  Usually, the client provides you a buffer, and you fill it in with the information.

Comment: I use a function in my IDE to get the values of the string but this function has in parameters the adress of the text that's why i need to return the adress of the string

Comment: @JoffreyAuray-Lorival What you "need" can't be done.  You cannot return the address of a local variable, so forget about it.  See my answer for the approach that many, if not most DLL functions use to handle string passing and returning.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to export string from extern "C" function:

1) Provide the second method to free release memory allocated:

```
extern "C" const char* getStr(...)
{
  auto result = new char[N];
  ...
  return result;
}
extern "C" void freeStr(const char* str)
{
   delete[] const_cast<char*>(str);
}
```

2) Use OS allocator, e.g. in case of Windows:

```
// Client must call SysFreeString later
extern "C" const char* getStr(...)
{
  auto result = SysAllocString(N);
  ...
  return result;
}
```

3) Use client-provided buffer (there are a lot of variations how to tell the client what size buffer should have).

```
extern "C" int getStr(char* buffer, int bufSize, ...){}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many answers to your question.  But one thing you *can't* do is return the address of a local variable.  Returning the address of a local variable is *undefined behavior*, so forget about that option completely.

Since you stated that the function is part of a DLL, then it is better to use the "standard" ways to handle strings between a DLL and the client application.

One usual and widely used method is to have the client create the char buffer, and have the char buffer passed to you.  Your function then fills in the user-supplied buffer with the information.  Optional items such as size of the buffer can also be passed.

The above method is used by most functions in the Windows API that requires passing and returning strings.

Here is a small example:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
char *rogner(char *buffer, int buflen)
{
    int tableauXY[2];
    tableauXY[0]=5;
    tableauXY[1]=8;

    string valeurs=to_string(tableauXY[0])+";"+to_string(tableauXY[1]);

    // get length of buffer and make sure we copy the correct
    // number of characters
    size_t minSize = std::min(buflen, valeurs.length());
    const char* val1=valeurs.c_str();
    memcpy(buffer, val1, minSize);

    // return the user's buffer back to them.
    return buffer;
}
```

There are variations to the above code, such as

1. returning the number of characters copied instead of the original buffer.
2. If `buflen==0`, only return the total number of characters that would be copied.  This allows the client to call your function to get the number of characters, and then call it a second time with
   the buffer of the appropriate size.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all, it works
I've used the PaulMcKenzie's method and it's good!
I have not tried the Nikerboker's solution so maybe it works too.

Thanks